# es6 super propMethod call super other propMethod

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I use nodejs 6.10.3 the code is show in below, I have problem for es6 class inheritance.

```
'use strict';

class Foo {
    constructor() {}
    hi() {
        console.log('foo.hi');
        this._hi();
    }
    _hi() {
        console.log('foo._hi');
    }
}

class Goo extends Foo {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    hi() {
        console.log('goo.hi');
        super.hi();
    }
    _hi() {
        console.log('goo._hi');
    }
}

let goo = new Goo();
goo.hi();
```

the console.log output is this.

```
// goo.hi
// foo.hi
// goo._hi
```

But I need to this.

```
// goo.hi
// foo.hi
// foo._hi
```

How can I do?

Comment: Simply don’t override the method ?

Answer (score 0):

`super` will initialize `this`

```js
'use strict';

class Foo {
    constructor() {}
    hi() {
        console.log('foo.hi');
        this._hi();
    }
    _hi() {
        console.log('foo._hi');
    }
}

class Goo extends Foo {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    hi() {
        console.log('goo.hi');
        Foo.prototype.hi();
    }
    _hi() {
        console.log('goo._hi');
    }
}

let goo = new Goo();
goo.hi();
```

Comment: Now `this` will refer to `Foo.prototype`. The method won’t have access to instance data.